# Wifi not working after uninstalling hostapd

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, networkmanager

I wanted to try creating a wireless hotspot for learning purposes, and [followed the answers in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap). I didn't like the result, and after also trying [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap), I decided I wanted to undo everything, which included uninstalling `hostapd`.

After uninstalling `hostapd` and restarting, my wifi no longer shows up in my network applet. Doing a `rfkill list all` shows a soft block:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I can do `rfkill unblock wifi` or `rfkill unblock all` which will change soft blocked state to `no`, but I am still unable to use my wifi.

Is there a way to undo the damage or reinstall my wifi? I am running Linux mint 19.3, which is based on Ubuntu 18.04. I have HWE installed.

Wireless info script dump: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DvZhggr6qY/

**EDIT:** at some point my wifi soft blocks stopped happening after rebooting. I'm unsure why.

Comment: try downloading `wireless-tools` (you should have them already) and running this `sudo iwlist scan wlo1` if the scan returns any access points in the area then it's the network manager applet that's faulty. If you get "Network is down" then do `rfkill unblock all` and turn the interface on `ifconfig wlo1 up`

Comment: Thanks @shiftas, you were right that I had to do `ifconfig wlo1 up` first. Before that, I get  `wlo1  Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down`. After the interface is up, `iwlist scan` successfully finds all my access points. My network manager GUI still doesn't show any sign of my wifi interface.

Comment: Then try to connect to your ap using `nmcli`, this should be installed on linux mint by default.  For a new connection `nmcli dev wlo1 connect <mySSID> password <myPassword>`  for an existing connection `nmcli con up <mySSID>` or `nmcli con up id <mySSID>`

Comment: @shiftas I tried `nmcli dev wlo1 connect <mySSID> password <myPassword>` but I get the error `Error: argument 'wlo1' not understood. Try passing --help instead`. Running `nmcli con up <mySSID>` returns `Error: unknown connection <MySSID>` (I put in my real SSID). I also tried `nmcli device wifi connect <MySSID> password "$pass"` but got `Error: No network with SSID '<MySSID>' found`.

Comment: I also noticed that `nmcli dev status` shows `wlo1` as unmanaged. So I tried `nmcli dev set wlo1 managed yes`, but it still shows as unmanaged. I also checked `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` and it looks ok: `[keyfile] unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan`

Comment: I still have my old saved wifi connections, which I can see with `nmcli connection show`. I tried connecting to my usual one with `nmcli c up uuid <UUID>` but got `Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.`

Comment: In your pasted script dump it says `Mode:Managed` so maybe it's `nmcli` that's the issue. Try using `wpa_cli`, here's a guide on how to connect using it https://shapeshed.com/linux-wifi/#how-to-connect-to-a-network-using-wpa_cli

Comment: @shiftas Attempting to run `wpa_cli` yields `Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: (nil) - re-trying`. I've tried various online solutions, but no success. What I've found interesting is that plugging in a usb wifi dongle actually works correctly in Network Manager, and `wpa_cli` also works with the wifi dongle. But as soon as I plug it out and try use my laptop's internal wifi, nothing works anymore. I believe my internal wifi may be blacklisted somewhere on the system, but I'm not sure where to check.

Comment: @shiftas I found the problem. I did a `grep wlo1 /etc/ -R` and found an entry in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` under `[keyfile]`: `unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlo1`. I commented out that line with a `#` and then did a `service network-manager restart`, and my wifi showed up :D. I would not have come to this answer without your help, so if you detail this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume your network device is `wlan0` for demonstration purposes. Replace `wlan0` with the name of your own interface. The interface name can be checked with `ifconfig -a`.

## Bring the interface up

First off, start by doing `ifconfig wlan0 up`.

## Check for soft blocks

Check if your device is soft blocked by running `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

If you have a soft block on your wireless device, run `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`. This persisted for me after reboots.

## Check for Network Manager problems

Determine if your NetworkManager is still managing your Wi-Fi by running `nmcli` or `nmcli dev status`. If it's marked as unmananged, you can try `dev set wlan0 managed yes`.

If this does not work for you, check `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. In my case, I had these offending lines:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlan0
```

I commented out the `unmanaged-devices=` line by putting a `#` in front of it and then running `service network-manager restart`, which resolved the issue for me.

## Other checks

More generally, you can try `grep wlan0 /etc/ -R` and inspect whatever files show up (this is how I discovered the unmanaged Wi-Fi line in Network Manager confs). Be sure to make backups of whatever you change.

Additionally, there are some troubleshooting commands in the comments of the original question.